# HttpClient not sending all cookies to restful api

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am calling a restful api using HttpClient 4.4.1, but it is not sending the cookies,

```
private CloseableHttpResponse call(String url, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    javax.servlet.http.Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
    BasicClientCookie basicClientCookie = null;
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            javax.servlet.http.Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
            basicClientCookie = new BasicClientCookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue());
            basicClientCookie.setDomain(cookie.getDomain());
            basicClientCookie.setPath("/");
            basicClientCookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR, "true");
            basicClientCookie.setVersion(0);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 100);
            Date date = calendar.getTime();
            basicClientCookie.setExpiryDate(date);
            cookieStore.addCookie(basicClientCookie);
        }
    }
    if (cookieStore.getCookies() != null) {
      System.out.println("Cookies size " + cookieStore.getCookies().size());
    }
    localContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request, localContext);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("msg " + e.getMessage());

    }
    return httpResponse;
}
```

I can see it is only sending the last cookie which has been added. What am i missing? Please help.

Comment: Where are you using `cookieStore` after populating it? Also, does `cookies` have all the cookies you need to send? Try printing its size.

Comment: Yes, it prints the cookies size to 13(correct size)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for sure in the code inside the for loop because only the last added cookie is visible.

Try to debug the for loop either using debugger or by adding the `system.out.println` statement before the loop when you are getting cookies array from request, than inside the loop when you are creating basic client cookie and then before and after adding basic client cookie to `cookiestore`

As suggested in the comments you have also not added `cookiestore` to the context.

```
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

Another problem with the above code is

```
basicClientCookie.setDomain(cookie.getDomain());
```

`cookie.getDomain()` and url of the `request` can be different and as per the cookies behaviour they should be same then only cookies will send.So only cookies having same url will be send with the request

Comment: Updated the question, cookiestore is added to localcontext. But still only the last cookie is sent.

Comment: Also print the domain of the each cookie and the url of the get request.They should have the same domain